# How to pass href with id to controller method Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, href

I have the following href function in my view and I have to attach a id ($group) to my route.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{{ route('show.invitation', {{$group}}) }}">Invite User to Group</a>
```

This is my web route.

```
Route::get('invitation/show{group}', 'InvitationController@show')->name('show.invitation');
```

I get this error message.

Missing required parameters for [Route: show.invitation] [URI: invitation/show/{group}]. (View: /Users/daniel/Documents/Development/Laravel/bolzer/resources/views/settinggroup/overview.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, edit your route

```
Route::get('invitation/show/{group}', 'InvitationController@show')->name('show.invitation');
```

with **route()** method, pass the name of the route

```
<a href="{{ route('show.invitation', $group) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Invite User to Group</a>
```

with **url()** method, pass URL of the route

```
<a href="{{ url('/invitation/show/', $group) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Invite User to Group</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Group variable should be concatenated with `route()`'s first parameter. Simply use `.` where you use `,`

```
href="{{ route('show.invitation'.{{$group}}) }}"
```

---

But the best practice is what @Sunil_kumawat say.

Answer (score 0):

simply pass the `$group` **NOT** the `{{$group}}` to the `route()` functions second parameter.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
    href="{{ route('show.invitation', $group) }}">
    Invite User to Group
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a key'd array() you can also define the specific elements within each URL, e.g:

```
<a href=" {{ route('some.example', ['group'=>$group, 'somename'=>...]) }}">Link</a>
```